# Get notified when describe changes (e.g. new picklist values or profile changes)

Tags: rest-api

I have a client application for mobile devices that interacts with Salesforce.

As part of the app configuration, I need to confirm that the user has access to some sObject fields and what picklist values there are.

We therefore do a series of `/describe` calls to those sObjects and save the data.

What I am looking for is if there is any way to know when this data is modified (e.g. when user's access to fields changed or when new picklists were added), as otherwise we end up using a lot of API calls by constantly checking all the time whether there are any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's typically not necessary to refresh constantly, because changes only rarely occur (outside of rare situations like testing). Just refresh daily or so.

Alternatively, use the [UI-API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm), which will communicate most types of changes to you every time you load a record from the database. It includes almost everything you need to render the UI, including the page layout and current record values. You won't need to describe as much.

Finally, keep in mind that you can [batch up to 25 requests at once](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm), which only counts as one API call, drastically reducing the calls needed.

Comment: Unfortunately as an ISV I beg to differ - our customers make these kind of changes about all the time, sadly, with hundreds of those field users affected. UI-API is good but requires me to make a call when I want to render edit UI, which would only increase amount of calls my app makes. 

Good point re: batching, i will test to see if it works with /describe.

Thank you as always @sfdcfox!

Comment: Actually your second link (batching) leads me to UI-API, too :(

Comment: @zaitsman haha, that's a copy-paste error, let me fix it.

Comment: the doco says `Each subrequest counts against rate limits.`. Do you have a source on your comments saying `which only counts as one API call`?

Comment: Actually i think you were referring to this API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm

In that one it does say that it is a single call. Now i wonder why they have two...

Comment: @zaitsman I've never used either, I presumed it was one per batch, which would make more sense.

Comment: I found nothing in the docos re: this explicitly but at least this post confirms that `batch` counts each request as it's own REST API call, but composite doesn't. Also `batch` has a Connect API burst rate limit and can't call to other `/composite` (e.g. `/composite/sobjects`) APIs so it seems like `/composite` is just the way to go.

https://webkul.com/blog/composite-resources-salesforce/

Comment: @zaitsman Oh, good to know. Yeah, I think batch mode is to simulate multiple API calls without the overhead of roundtrips? Anyways, useful info.